# nginx not listening to port 80

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-12.04

I've just installed a Ubuntu 12.04 server and nginx 1.2.7, removed `default` from sites-enabled and added my own file into `sites-available` and symlink at `sites-enabled`. Then restarted nginx.

**Problem:** However going to the URL does not load the site. `netstat -nlp | grep nginx` and `netstat -nlp | grep 80` both returns no results! `lsof -i :80` also returns nothing. A `dig` from another server returns the correct ip address so it shouldn't be a DNS problem. I was able to connect to apache which I have now stopped its service. nginx logs also shows nothing.

How should I troubleshoot this problem?

**/etc/nginx/site-available/mysite.com**

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com *.mysite.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    root /var/www/mysite/public;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

}
```

Comment: that show `nginx -t`?

Comment: Are you running it as superuser? Also, is something else already listening to that port (`lsof -i :80`)? If you're not superuser, this *will* fail, unless the binary has been granted `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` see [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html). Last but not least, if you're testing from the outside world, check your firewall settings.